# Where is the execstack in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, yum

I want to mark the binary as not requiring executable stack on CentOS 7.2 with `execstack`, but there is no such utility and `yum` does not find package `execstack`. Why is this the case? Is this utility is not used now?

```
[root@localhost bin]# execstack
-bash: execstack: command not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`execstack` is provided by the package `prelink` in centos-7. Here,

http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/prelink-0.5.0-9.el7.x86_64.rpm

```
~]$ rpm -qlp http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/prelink-0.5.0-9.el7.x86_64.rpm | grep exec
/usr/bin/execstack
/usr/share/man/man8/execstack.8.gz


# install using YUM
~]$ yum install prelink
```